# O caminho do comando iniciar do mysql não está definido?

Tags: mysql, netbeans

Estou tentando conectar web-service no netbeans no ubuntu com mysql server, porém qdo clico em iniciar da esse erro da imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um servidor MySQL deve ser inicializado (bem como reiniciado, finalizado etc.) por meio da linha de comando. Normalmente esse comando fica em:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql
```

Para iniciar o servidor, basta passar `start` como argumento, assim:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Use esse comando no seu Netbeans.